# What are the units of the variance/rate parameter in a 1D continuous Brownian diffusion process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

In a 1-dimensional continuous Brownian diffusion process following the SDE:
$$
dx(t) = \sigma dW(t)
$$
where $W(t)$ represents the Wiener process, what are the units of $\sigma$?

Given that the probability density of, say, $x(s) = 0$ at time $s>0$, given that at time $0$ $x(0) = 0$, is $0 \sim N(0, \sigma^2 s)$, is $\sigma^2$ in $\frac{x^2}{unit \: time}$?

Answer (score 1):

Involving irrational function in $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2t)$,

We must have in terms of dimension :

$$ [\sigma^2t]=1$$

so

$$ [\sigma]=T^{-1/2}$$

**Conclusion**

$W(t)$ Wiener process is of a dimension of $[L.T^{1/2}]$ unit of $m.t^{-1/2}$ ISU and $\sigma$ is of a dimension of $[T^{-1/2}]$ unit of $t^{-1/2}$ ISU.

ISU means International System of Unit.

Comment: W itself is in units of length (or whatever $x$'s units are). It is $dW$ whose units involve time.

Comment: Actually $dW$ is a differential form of $W$ so it is same unit as $W$. Proof : the differential is $\sum \frac{\partial W}{\partial x_i}d{x_i}$

Comment: Speaking more carefully, there are different ways to group units depending on how you do the scaling analysis. You can set it up so $\sigma$ is nondimensional, for example, and then $dW$ is just a length (which is a natural thing to want to do, so that the Wiener process itself can be interpreted as the position of a Brownian particle). But to do that you have to scale time up front.

Comment: Interesting thanks !